# "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" even when using an exception

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, for-loop, plsql

I'm having issues with my PL-SQL code since I have a for loop that inserts rows into a table, the thing is that sometimes tries to insert repeated values so I'm getting the ORA-00001 error.
I added a exception to avoid this but it seems not to be working... can you please help me? :)

Here is my code (the one getting errors):

```
 if (x = 1) then
         if (proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo,   asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo) is not null) then
            begin
            insert into proyeccion (alumno_codigo, asignatura_codigo, proyeccionestado_codigo) 
                        values (alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo), 1);
            EXCEPTION 
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN 
               update proyeccion set asignatura_codigo=proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo) 
               where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
            end;
         end if; 
      end if;
```

This is the function mentioned above:

```
create or replace function proyec(cod_alum alumno.alumno_codigo%type, plan_cod   alumno.plan_codigo%type, cod_asig asignatura.asignatura_codigo%type)
   return number is
asig number;
begin
   select asignatura_codigo
   into asig
   from requisito
   where requisito_codigo=cod_asig and 
         plan_codigo=plan_cod and 
         asignatura_codigo in (select asignatura_codigo from matricula where alumno_codigo=cod_alum);
   return asig;
end;
/
```

Here is the full main code for reference:

```
set serveroutput on size 10000
declare
   cursor alum is
      select alumno_codigo, plan_codigo 
      from alumno
      where alumno_codigo in (select alumno_codigo from matricula where alumno_codigo = alumno.alumno_codigo);
   cursor asig is
      select asignatura_codigo
      from asignatura;
   x number;
begin
   for alumno_rec in alum loop
      update alumno set alumno_promedio=prom(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo) where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo; 
      update alumno set alumno_semestre=sem(cred(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo)) where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
      if (perdida(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo)>1) then
         update alumno set alumnoestado_codigo=3 where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
      end if;
      for asignatura_rec in asig loop
          select alumnoestado_codigo into x from alumno where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
          if (perdida2(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo)=2) then
             update alumno set alumnoestado_codigo=3 where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
          elsif (perdida2(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo)>2) then 
             update alumno set alumnoestado_codigo=4 where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
          elsif x is null then
             update alumno set alumnoestado_codigo=1 where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
          end if;
          if (x = 1) then
             if (proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo) is not null) then
                begin
                insert into proyeccion (alumno_codigo, asignatura_codigo, proyeccionestado_codigo) 
                        values (alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo), 1);
                EXCEPTION 
                WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN 
                   update proyeccion set asignatura_codigo=proyec(alumno_rec.alumno_codigo, alumno_rec.plan_codigo, asignatura_rec.asignatura_codigo) 
               where alumno_codigo=alumno_rec.alumno_codigo;
                end;
             end if; 
          end if;
      end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Maybe the update statement generates the ORA-00001?

Comment: Like Rene said - check all of your unique constraints on the table. I bet the column asignatura_codigo is in one of them and your update statement breaks the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception cannot be directly used in functions;

According to the Oracle documentation the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception will not propagate the

exception if run

in a query: "Because this exception is used internally by some SQL functions to signal

that

they are

finished, you should not rely on this exception being propagated if you raise it within a

function that is

called as part of a query."

Comment: Please declare the exception if you want it to be propogated in the function